# exist hosting for ruby rack apps?

Tags: ruby, hosting, rack

exist hosting for ruby rack apps?

Please help me

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[Heroku](http://Heroku) is good for hosting all things ruby, not just rails. I do host a pure rack app there too. It is best to use `puma`as your web server though.